# Regex: How to capture words with spaces/hyphens excluding numbers?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Column1
-------
abcd - efghi 1234
aasdas - asdas 54321
asda-asd 2344
aasdas(asd) 5234
```

I want to be able to pull everything out that will exclude a number so it will look like this:

```
Column2
-------
abcd - efghi
aasdas - asdas
asda-asd
aasdas(asd)
```

This is my current regex:

```
df['Column2'] = df['Column1'].str.extract('([A-Z]\w{0,})', expand=True)
```

But it only extracts out the first word that excludes parenthesis and hyphens. Any help will be appreciated...thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like using `replace`

```
df.Column1.str.replace('\d+','')
Out[775]: 
0      abcd-efghi 
1    aasdas-asdas 
2        asda-asd 
3     aasdas(asd) 
Name: Column1, dtype: object
#df.Column1=df.Column1.str.replace('\d+','')
```

Comment: Thanks! The answer always seems so easy but I can never come up with it D:

Comment: Adding a .str.strip() at the end formats it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just removing numbers will leave you with unwanted space characters.

This list comprehension removes all digits and keeps
space characters, but removes them on the outside.

```
df['Column2'] = df['Column1'].apply(
                   lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x if not i.isdigit()]).strip())
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!